# Uploaded files goes to uploads folder but wrong directory in sql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I created a form that will upload files to my "Upload" Folder, it saves to the folder but my sql table shows the wrong directory in the field. SQL should be uploads/filename.pdf not filename.pdf. My upload script is:

```
<?php

require_once ('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);           
$xfile=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$xdate=$_POST['date'];
$xmemo=$_POST['memo'];
$xtitle=$_POST['title'];

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO memo (date, memo, file, title)
VALUES ('$xdate', '$xmemo', '$xfile', '$xtitle')";

$conn->exec($sql);
echo "<script>alert('Successfully Added!!!'); window.location='view.php'</script>";
// }
}
// }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following line:

```
$xfile=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

here `$xfile` contains only file name not the file name + file path, then how you can expect by using it you can get file name + file path. To do it so, append the path with file name at the time of insert like:

```
"INSERT INTO memo (date, memo, file, title)
VALUES ('$xdate', '$xmemo', 'uploads/' . '$xfile', '$xtitle')";
```

or store the path + file name in a variable and use that variable.

Comment: Sounds great !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$xfile=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

$_FILES["file"]["name"] will only return file name.

You can do like this to store folder name,

```
$xfile= 'uploads/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

**Advice**

There is no need of storing folder name in your database, just store file name. When you're retrieving file append folder name. example :

```
<img src="uploads/"<?= $file ?>>
```

`$file` is a file name coming from database.